# How to return to main code after jump in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

```
.stack 100h

.data    

~the offsets here

total db 0

mesajfinal db ' intrebari corecte din 4',13,10,'$'

**.code**

mov ax,@data

mov ds,ax

mov ah,9h


mov dx,offset m11

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m12

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m13

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m14

int 21h

mov ah,1

int 21h

mov bl,al

cmp bl,'2'

je @CORECT

jmp @GRESIT


>**;there i want to continue after jump**

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m21

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m22

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m23

int 21h

mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset m24

int 21h

mov ah,1

int 21h

mov bl,al

cmp bl,'2'

je @CORECT

jmp @GRESIT




@CORECT:

inc total

mov ah, 2

mov dl,0ah

int 21h

mov dl,0dh

int 21h


@GRESIT:

mov ah, 2

mov dl,0ah

int 21h

mov dl,0dh

int 21h






mov dl,total

add dl,48

mov ah,2

int 21h



mov ah,9h

mov dx,offset mesajfinal

int 21h

mov ah,4ch

int 21h

end
```

i m very new to asembly and i tried to make a quizz in asembly x86 where the question and the answers show on screen, the user imputs the answer(from 1 to 3) and if its the right answer it inc total of points
the problem is that after the first question it already show me the final mesaj with the final number of points , skipping the other questions

Comment: Why do you revert all other improvements made by other community members, including typo fixing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you learn how `call` and `ret` work you can have your program jump to another place and then return where you came from.

Answer (score 2):

### If you didn't jump away, then you wouldn't have to jump back

For a correct answer you increment the *total* variable and output a newline.
For a bad answer you just output a newline.

The easy (and short) solution is to output the newline together with the messages (I have added an extra byte **10** right before the **$** marker), and then do the incrementing of the *total* variable locally.
Tip: You can output the 4 strings all at once

```
...
m11 db 'In ce an a fost lansat procesorul Intel 8086?',13,10
    db '1. 1980',13,10
    db '2. 1978',13,10
    db '3. 1986',13,10,10,'$'

m21 db 'In ce zi a fost lansat sistemul de operare WINDOWS 10?',13,10
    db '1. 12 iulie 2014',13,10
    db '2. 24 octombrie 2015',13,10
    db '3. 29 iulie 2015',13,10,10,'$'

  ...

@Q1:
  mov dx, offset m11    ;
  mov ah, 09h           ; Just 1 output needed
  int 21h               ;
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h
  cmp al, '2'           ;
  jne @Q2               ;
  inc total             ; Do this locally (close to the Q/A)
@Q2:                    ;
  mov dx, offset m21
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h
  cmp al, '2'
  jne @Q3
  inc total
@Q3:

  ...

@Final:
  mov dl, total
  add dl, 48
  mov ah, 02h
  int 21h

  ...
```